# TypeScript default constant export

Tags: javascript, typescript, typings

Tenemos una librería TypeScript que estamos publicando a un entorno de NPM privado y queremos usarla en otros proyectos ya sean en TS, ES6 o ES5.

Digamos que la librería es un paquete npm llamado `foo`, cuyo fichero principal funciona como un "barrel" realizando lo siguiente:

```
// Index.ts
import Foo from './Core/Foo';

export {default as Foo} from './Core/Foo';

const foo = new Foo();

export default foo;
```

Queremos exportar la clase principal de la librería, así como una instancia por defecto de la misma para que las aplicaciones la usen sin crear una nueva, a no ser que sea necesario.

Además, hemos creado los ficheros de definiciones en un repositorio separado de forma similar a DefinitelyTyped:

```
// foo.d.ts
namespace Foo {
  export class Foo {
    public constructor()
    // ...methods
  }

  const foo: Foo;

  export default foo;
}

module 'foo' {
  export = Foo;
}
```

Al correr los tests falla con:

> error TS1063: An export assignment cannot be used in a namespace.

Lo que buscamos es usar la instancia por defecto de la siguiente manera:

```
// ES5, browser env
window.Foo.foo.someMethod();

// ES6/TS
import foo from 'foo';

foo.someMethod();
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer esto correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado! [Post original en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658833/typescript-default-constant-export)

La solución es olvidarse del namespace y dejarlo todo como declaración de módulo:

```
// foo.d.ts
declare module 'foo' {
  export class Foo {
    public constructor();
    public method(): void;
  }

  const foo: Foo;

  export default foo;
}
```

Y cualquier módulo que vaya a extenderlo, debe realizar los imports dentro de su declaración de módulo:

```
// bar.d.ts
declare module 'bar' {
  import {
    Foo
  } from 'foo';

  export class Bar extends Foo {
    public constructor();
    public anotherMethod(): void;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al estar implementando la librería en TypeScript no es necesario construir los archivos de definición de tipos manualmente porque se pueden aprovechar los generados por el proceso de compilación de TypeScript

Para ello hay que establecer la opción de compilación `"declaration": true` en el archivo `tsconfig.json` y, al copilar el proyecto, se generarán los archivos de definición de tipos en el mismo directorio de compilación.

```
//archivo index.d.ts
import { Foo } from './Foo';
export { Foo } from './Foo';
export declare const foo: Foo;

//archivo Foo.d.ts
export class Foo {
    public constructor();
    public method(): void;
}
```

Además, si en el archivo `package.json` de tu librería añades la propiedad `"types"` haciendo referencia al archivo `index.d.ts` el proceso de compilación de typescript sabrá encontrar los tipos de tu librería

```
//archivo package.json de la librería foo
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/foo.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo de tipo esto en [este](https://github.com/rsciriano/tiny-ts-modular-sample) repositorio de GitHub

> Nota: esto funciona a partir de TypeScript 2.0

Por último, también hay un proyecto llamado [dts-bundle](https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle) con el que podrías generar archivo único que juntase todos los archivos `.d.ts` de tu librería (incluyendo la definición de módulo)

Comment: dts-bundle creo que ya lo había probado. Voy a probar el ejemplo de tu repositorio, imagino que esto funcionará bien junto con los ficheros de definiciones externos de _typings_ también?

Comment: Nosotros estamos usando `dts-bundle` para generar la definición de tipos, pero desde las últimos cambios en la 2.0 con [los tipos en paquetes NPM (los que comienzan con @types)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/), creo que pronto empezaremos a usar solo NPM